# Use a superclass instance with subclass instances

Tags: java, object, inheritance, polymorphism

My goal is to create a super-class *Product*

with different objects created with this superclass, for example:

- *USB stick 8gb*
- *HHD 1tb*
- *SSD 512gb*

all with different values (like price).

And a sub-class to create different objects of those products (in the case of for example *USB stick 8gb*: I have 5 (objects) in total: 1. new, 2. used, 3. used, 4. new, 5. new)

With my version (see above) you would always need to give every version (1-5) the same parameters

```
Item usbstick1;
usbstick1 = new Item(50, "3.0 USB-Stick with 8 Gigybytes of storage", true)
```

How do I achieve:

a) Only put a reference of the already created "product" (like *USB Stick 8gb*) each time you create a new subclass-object?

b) How do I use this reference for different sub-classes?

If I have this **super-class**

```
public class Product {

    double price
    String description

    public Item(double price, String description) {
        setPrice(price);
        setDescription(descrition);
    }

    setPrice(double newPrice) {
        price=newPrice;
    }
    public void setDescription(String newDescription) {
        description=newDescription;
    }
```

This **subclass**

```
public class Item extends Product {
    boolean sealed;

    public Item(double price, String description, boolean sealed) {
        super(price, description);
        setSealed(sealed);
    }

    public void setSealed(newSealed) {
        sealed=newSealed;
    }
```

Aa well as this **subclass**

```
public class UsedItem extends Product {
    int usedDays;

    public UsedItem(double price, String description, int usedDays) {
        super(price, description);
        setUsedDays(usedDays);
    }

    public void setUsedDays(newUsedDays) {
        usedDays=newUsedDays;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider changing your `UsedItem` class to have an instance of Product, instead of extending it, and then passing a product in the constructor:

```
public class UsedItem {

   Product product;
   int usedDays;

   public UsedItem(Product product) {
       this.product = product;
   }

   public void setUsedDays(newUsedDays) {
       usedDays=newUsedDays;
   }
}
```

And then to make new `UsedItem`s you can just pass it the same product instance you make:

```
Item usbstick;
usbstick = new Item(50, "3.0 USB-Stick with 8 Gigybytes of storage", true);

UsedItem usb1 =  new UsedItem(usbstick);
UsedItem usb2 =  new UsedItem(usbstick);
UsedItem usb3 =  new UsedItem(usbstick);
```

Alternatively, you can set your used item to take an Item in a constructor and set the values from that:

```
public class UsedItem extends Item{

   public UsedItem(Product product) {
       super(product.price, product.description);
   }
}
```